# Customizing Skype menu item

Tags: c++, skype, skype4com

I want to add menu Item "My Setting" in Skype. As far as I know, [`Skpye4Com`](http://developer.skype.com/accessories/skype4com) has interface to create Skype Client. We can create Skype plugin with it but we cannot customize Skype itself. Right now, I am looking for an API through which I would be able to customize Skype.

Please suggest me whether this is possible or not and whether such an API exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's simply not possible. Skype is not open-source, so the API that is provided [here](http://developer.skype.com/accessories) seems to be the only way to develop something skype-related. Otherwise it's not possible to anyhow change skype's own code to customize it or build your own version of it.

Comment: @Siner Yeah its not open source..but if you see outlook and other Ms Windows Product, they  are also not open source,but they have provided COM api to add these things...that why i was wondering similar api provided by Skype as well....anyway